# How to explain this description of y' to someone who hasn't taken calculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition

How can I explain the equation $y' = \frac {dy}{dx}=f(y)g(x)$ to someone who has only taken precalculus?

Context: a friend asked my to explain the first page of my PDE textbook. I found it amazingly challenging to describe exactly (or at all) the difference between each side of the equivalence.

I said: y' is just a symbol we use to denote the idea that a number y is changing in relation to something else. The next part shows that the "something else" is x. In fact, when x changes a bit and y changes a bit, the ratio between those two changes is going to be dy/dx.

I couldn't find a good way to describe the last part though.

Comment: Side note: this is not just because I want to be able to explain well. I'm curious how people with little math background can still understand more complicated math ideas, and how that can inform my own thinking. I keep getting reminded of Thurston's 37th way of thinking about the derivative...

Comment: I'd ask him/her to take calculus.

Comment: I think this is the fundamental way that education is broken.  We've bought into the (very) false notion that everything is explainable to everyone.  But what sort of sorry science or philosophy or art is it, that anyone can understand it in one paragraph?  A decent discipline requires discipline and a lot of it.  When John Tate won the Abel Prize, he was asked by the local newspaper reporter to explain his work for the layman.  He said, "I can't, it's too complicated for the layman."  Hurray for John.

Comment: Math is very structured subject, you can't build without a foundation. Derivative can be explained as "speed of change in $y$ caused by change in $x$"

Comment: While I'm ranting:  This is the same nonsense behind "Calculus made easy."  We stupidly let the education people dictate to us that all math has to be easy.  But there are some bites that can't be cut into smaller pieces.  Students don't need smaller pieces, they need bigger mouths.

Comment: @B.Goddard, if you read my question, comment, and tags, you might notice I was not asking for a rant on our broken education system--I was asking for a way to explain the given equation. I think that a good teacher should be able to suggest some intuition of the derivative to someone who's taken precalc?

Comment: While on the subject, though--perhaps one of the "fundamental" ways education is broken is that smart people like you (and Tate!) who know math well are quicker to say "I can't, it's too complicated" than "let me try and explain."

Comment: @JohnHughes If you read my comment, then you'd see it was a "comment", not an "answer."  Answers go in the big boxes down below.  Sure, I can suggest intuition day in and day out.  But that doesn't mean the listener will be enlightened and I'm not a bad teacher just because none of the 100 ways I explained "derivative" somehow doesn't click with the student.  80-20 rule.